# How to make graphic caption rotate?

Tags: captions, rotating

I have a large graph that has to fit the paper in the landscape mode, therefore I have to rotate the graph using `includegraphics[angle=-90]`. However, the usual `\caption{}` statement remains the same as before, so that even though the graph is rotated, the caption is not. Is there a way to rotate both the graph the its caption accordingly? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}...\end{sidewaysfigure}
```